# Clone or edit local Minimongo collection

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I'd like to clone a minimongo collection so I can do some calculations, get a result, then push those results back to the server.

Assuming this is a suitable pattern, how best can I clone a minimongo collection?

It appears that in the object no longer has a `._deepcopy` (1.0.4), and attempting an `EJSON.clone` exceeds the callstack size for even tiny collections. Underscore's `_.clone()` only copies by reference.

Alternatively, I could just edit the local collection via `collection._collection.update`. But if that's the case, what would happen if on the off chance the server updated or removed a doc while it was processing? I watched this video, but am still unclear on that scenario: https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-how-does-the-client-synchronize-writes-with-the-server

Answer (score 0):

The *why* behind your pattern escapes me but one solution could be to define a *null collection,* ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)) copy the records you need to that, do your work, and then copy back the results into the original collection for automatic sync back to the server.

```
 myLocalCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```